# Need help figuring out why my loop outputs negative numbers

Tags: c#

My for loop keeps out putting negative numbers I can't seem to figure it out. I've looked around the internet and can't seem to find anything. So i'm asking here for help

```
int fuzzles = 1;// Starting number of fuzzles
int hours = 24;//hours to multiply
int totalFuzzles = 0; //starting off with 1 fuzzle
for(int i = 0; i < fuzzles; i*=2 ) {
    fuzzles = fuzzles *2; //double every fuzzle
    totalFuzzles = fuzzles; //save total of fuzzles
    int fuzzlesPerHour = totalFuzzles * hours; //multiply total and hours to get final product
    Console.WriteLine(fuzzlesPerHour);
}
```

Comment: You should start by fixing your indentation.

Comment: It’s indented correctly but I’m not really sure how to use stack overflow correct but thanks for the advice

Comment: You change the value of _fuzzles_ inside the loop. The same value used to check for exit condition. The loop continues until fuzzles reaches int.MaxValue then doubling it again it becomes negative. Perhaps you should explain what are you trying to do here. What should be the exit condition from your loop?

Comment: Also here your i starts from 0, and then in your loop definition you multiply it by 2, keeping the value of i a constant 0. I'm not sure what is your intention here.

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems here:

1. `Fuzzles` grows exponentially. Within not many iterations, it will exceed the max. integer value and overflow into the negatives.
2. `i` starts at 0 and you increase it by multiplication. Anything multiplied by 0 is 0, so this would be an infinite loop if it weren't for `fuzzles` overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

As @Verpous mentioned, it is because your `for loop` is infinite, Fuzzles overflows and returns negative numbers:

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you are trying to print the growth of Fuzzles right?

Following snipped would help.

```
        int fuzzles = 1;// Starting number of fuzzles
        int hours = 24;//hours to multiply
        for(int i = 0; i < hours; i++ ) {
            fuzzles = fuzzles *2; //double every fuzzle
            Console.WriteLine(fuzzles);
        }
```

Working code --> http://tpcg.io/s2O8gL5S